# Obtaining files from remote host via intermediary in scp

Tags: ssh, scp

I've been trying to get my head around this problem for a day now, I don't understand the following:

let's say I have three computers, namely A,B and C. I have files on C, which can be accessed only by B, which can be accessed only by A. SO:

```
C<B<A.
```

I need to get my folder from C to A. I know this is some sort of generic question with a generic solution, I've tried the following:

```
scp -r -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p name1@hostB" FOLDER   localhost:/some folder
```

This doesn't work for me from remote to local, but when I do it from local to remote it works. I tried to specify localhost as:

```
/home/user/
```

and `user@localhost:~`

What am I doing wrong here?

PS>

From remote if I want to transfer from A to C, it works fine.

```
scp -r -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p name1@hostB" FOLDER   name2@hostC:~
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens ? And what is the exact command with your different tries.

Comment: cp: cannot create regular file '/home/user/': Not a directory